# When does room delete entities from database?

Tags: android, android-room

I have a view that shows some data and uses a standard repository pattern.

1. Fragment calls repo in `onCreateView` and observe
2. Repo returns cached data in the database as LiveData (using room)
3. Repo calls a network request to get the real data (using retrofit2)
4. Repo saves the network response to the database (using room)

The fragment shows the up-to-date data correctly. However, when I leave the fragment that shows the data, the cached data is deleted from the local database. I confirmed that data is saved to the database and then deleted using Database Inspector on Android Studio. I don't even have a Delete query in my dao. Dao only has insert and select queries.

How could this be happening? Is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `@Insert` query in room can cascade delete other connected entities if it is marked with

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

You don't necessarily have to have a `@Delete` query.